# How to wrap getSelection() with multiple elements when it crosses node boundaries

Tags: javascript, dom, selection

Here is what I am doing to wrap the text selected with an element :

```
let selectObj = window.getSelection();
let wrapTag = document.createElement("a");

const range = selectObj.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
range.surroundContents(wrapTag);
selectObj.removeAllRanges();
selectObj.addRange(range);
```

But it won't work if the selection crosses text node boundaries, so I thought I could do an other wrap for every nodes crossed so instead of failing like this (text selected is inside the a tag):

```
<div>
    Lorem 
    <b>ipsum
    <a>dolor</b> sit</a>
    amet
</div>
```

It creates two wraps like this:

```
<div>
    Lorem
    <b>ipsum <a>dolor</a></b>
    <a>sit</a>
    amet
</div>
```

Do you know how I can achieve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty simple thanks to the [Rangy](https://github.com/timdown/rangy/wiki) library, it contain a "createClassApplier" module wich can wrap any cross-boundary selection with multiple wraps if needed.

You can get it with:

```
npm install rangy
```

Code example:

```
import rangy from 'rangy/lib/rangy-classapplier';

rangy.init();
let rangyOptions = {};
let rangyWrapper = rangy.createClassApplier("your-class", rangyOptions);
rangyWrapper.applyToSelection();
```

You can specify many options in the second parameter (change the default span tag, add attributes etc...), you can check [every options here](https://github.com/timdown/rangy/wiki/Class-Applier-Module).